# Why does my JGit checkout return null ref?

Tags: java, git, kotlin, jgit

I've the following code:

```
fun checkoutBranch(path: Path, name: String) {
    Git.open(path.toFile()).use { git ->
        val branchExists = git
                .branchList()
                .setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.ALL)
                .call()
                .filterNot { it.name.startsWith("refs/remotes/") }
                .map { it.name }
                .any { it.endsWith(name) }
        val ref = git
                .checkout()
                .setCreateBranch(!branchExists)
                .setName(name)
                .setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK)
                .call()
    }
}
```

When I call it with `name = master`, everything works as expected. A subsequent call with `name = test` causes a new branch to be created, but `ref` is `null`. Looking at [CheckoutCommand#L285](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommand.java#L285), it seems that `ref.name = refs/heads/master` for `master`, but for `test`, `ref.name = refs/tags/test`, and `ref` is then set to `null`.

```
Ref ref = repo.findRef(name);
if (ref != null && !ref.getName().startsWith(Constants.R_HEADS))
    ref = null;
```

What is happening here? Is this the expected behavior for a new branch? By going into the repo, I can see that it is in detached HEAD state, perhaps causing this issue.

Comment: `refs/tags/test` means `test` is a tag. Checking out a tag leads to detached HEAD status.

Comment: @ElpieKay Well, that much I gathered, but why is it checking out a tag? I just said "test", didn't say it was a tag or branch or what.

Comment: Maybe the repository happens to have an existing tag `test`.

Comment: @ElpieKay yes, that's it! I solved the issue by explicitly specifying the name as `refs/heads/test`. This seems to be a bug. For a create branch command, `repo.findRef` should resolve to a branch, not a tag by the same name.

Comment: Note that a tag `refs/tags/xxx` is one of Git refs, and so is a branch under the namespace `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/`. Besides, users are allowed to create defined refs under other namespaces. So I think it's reasonable `repo.findRef` can resolve to a tag.

Comment: Note also that Git itself generally prefers tags over branches when there is both a `refs/tags/X` and `refs/head/X`: it's chosen in step 3, before reaching step 4, in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html (I have no idea whether JGit follows Git's scheme here though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ElpieKay for the clue. The problem was caused by the presence of a tag named `test`. Apparently, JGit prefers tags over branches when looking for references.

I solved the issue by explicitly specifying the branch name as `refs/heads/test` (in `setName`).